# I don't understand the outcome of the solution for a circuit with two voltage sources and an inductor

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]I have solved this circuit problem and I don't really understand the result in terms of power for the two sources.

So for source one, it is clearly generating real and reactive power.
For source two, it is consuming, based on the current going out of the source.
The reactive power consuming reactive power.

The results shows the new power in the circuit is almost zero.
But the reactive power is not zero, the consumed is way more than the generation and that does not make sense.

Is there a problem with my math?

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: Please post the entire question before your work.

Comment: I have uploaded the question, it is part d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you draw your current I with a reference direction to the right.  So, this current I is (V1-V2)/j5.  That will correct your phase angle.

Second, to calculate the power quantities coming from source V2 you need to use -I which will just be I with angle shifted by +/- 180 degrees.

See if that clears it up for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The answer now make more sense. The source on the right is consuming real power and generating reactive while the other source supplying the real power and consuming a small portion of the reactive power. The inductive load the major reactive power consumer. So in this case, it means the source 1 is a generator and source 2 is a motor.

Comment: You are welcome.  The source on the left is absorbing 1200 watts and 78.5 vars.  The source on the right is producing 1200 watts and 801 vars.

Answer (score 0):

If you calculate (V2-V1)I* - the power in the inductor- you will find the missing reactive power (and zero real power, of course).